# How to bind Image coordinates on Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, binding, coordinates

I have an Image(named `car1`) on grid and i want to bind `car1` coordinates to `textblock`.

```
<Canvas>
    <Image Name="car1" />
</Canvas>

<WrapPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="" Margin="10" Name="xx" Width="50"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Text="" Margin="10" Name="yy" Width="50">0</TextBlock>
</WrapPanel>
```

How to solve it ?

Comment: where is the `Grid` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Canvas>
            <Image Name="car1" Canvas.Left="40" Canvas.Top="30"/>
        </Canvas>

        <WrapPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(Canvas.Left), ElementName=car1}" Margin="10" Name="Left" Width="50"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(Canvas.Top), ElementName=car1}" Margin="10" Name="Top" Width="50"/>
        </WrapPanel>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```